# How to select particular label in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have attached here my screenshot, I need to select red bordered label in css. how i can select that particular label. [image: label selection]

Comment: Set a class or id?...

Comment: Please avoid placing screenshots of code - we prefer code to be placed within the question as formatted text

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit the HTML you can target elements by their attributes. So for this you could do:

```
label[for="value-here"]{
  /* styles */
}
```

By as stated, it is best to give the element a class or some unique identifier for the purposes of targeting it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `for_value` with that pretty long name.

```
label[for="for_value"] {
  /* CSS Properties */
}
```

Best is to assign a class for the label.

**HTML**

```
<label class="new-label"></label>
```

**CSS**

```
.new-label {
 /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class or id to it and access it using class/id name.

```
<label class="my_label" id="my_label_id" for="rn_Select"><span></span></label>
```

**css**

```
    .my_label{
    /*style goes here*/
    }

   #my_label_id{
    /*style goes here*/
   }
```

Comment: I fount solution
.disclaimer-option input + label {
    margin-top: -45px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using for value with same text I don't recommend you to use `label[for="for_value"]` but you're using defining id in input and next to it the label is there which you want to select as a selector. So, you may use [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

```
input#your_input_id + label{
   /*css rules*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a situation on our WooCommerce site where the "Add to cart" button was right next to a custom product field, and I needed to drop the product field below the button. In order to make it look right, I needed to be able to select the label for an input field. This is the CSS that ended up doing the trick for me.

`#product-57310 label[for="wcj_product_input_fields_local_1"] { display: -webkit-box!important; margin-top: 80px; }`

Where "#product-57310" is the ID of the product in woocommerce, so that it only applies to the specific product page and not every product page, and where "label[for="wcj_product_input_fields_local_1"]" is targeting the first label specifically to get under the "Add to cart" button.